# How compare char (or wchar_t) as part of string in c++

Tags: c++, string, localization, compare

I have two C-style null-terminated **(wide)strings** (*not `std::wstring`*) and I go through them by iterators and want to compare them char by char (for sorting). I don't need to use standard operators (`==`, `>`, `<`), because  I want to compare them by local rules (with **_locale_t** set).

I found only `_wcsicmp_l(wchar_t*, wchar_t*, _locale_t)`, which can compare two strings, not chars.

When I pass a pointer to `wchar_t` arguments on a to comparing function, like a part of a string (iterator of string), the function gets it like a pointer to string and is comparing two whole strings, not only chars.

I think an example will be more illustrated. Is it a good way, or is it too difficult and slow? Is there a way to do it easier?

The destination is providing natural sorting - strings includes chars and numbers.

```
inline bool compareChars(const wchar_t& lhs, const wchar_t& rhs)
{
    //I have to add terminate \0 here, in otherwise comparator compare string from lhs to end, not only chars
    wchar_t str_lhs[2]{ lhs, L'\0' }, str_rhs[2]{ rhs, L'\0' };
    _locale_t loc = _create_locale(LC_ALL, "cs-CZ.utf8");
    bool res = _wcsicoll_l(&str_lhs[0], &str_rhs[0], loc) < 0;
    _free_locale(loc);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    const wchar_t* firstStr = L"Test", * secondStr = L"Test2";
    const wchar_t* it1 = firstStr;
    const wchar_t* it2 = secondStr;
    const wchar_t* itEnd1 = it1;
    while (*itEnd1 != '\0')itEnd1++;
    const wchar_t* itEnd2 = it2;
    while (*itEnd2 != '\0')itEnd2++;

    for (; it1 != itEnd1; ++it1) //Go througth first string
        for (; it2 != itEnd2; ++it2) //Go througth second string
        {
            int res = compareChars(*it1, *it2); //chars like a part of string
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you **widestrings** regular null terminated (wide) strings?

Comment: You can't, generally, compare character by character and at the same time follow locale rules. Collation rules in many locales are trickier than that. E.g. in Spanish, the two-letter combination `ch` sorts as if it were a single letter between `c` and `d`. In French, strings are first compared disregarding diacritics, and then ties are broken by comparing diacrtitics backward, from last character to the first.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? Why do you want to do that? Currently, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Yes, they are regular null terminated strings

Comment: I want to do a natural sort (strings included strings and numbers)

Comment: I just have understood, why it is not possible to do localized comparing with chars only. In czech langugage is for exaple ....g - h - ch - i - j .... It is clear....

Comment: Given that you want to include a rule for sorting natural numbers, you could try partitioning the string into sections. For example, in each string you scan for the first digit (if any) and you then compare the substrings up to those digits. If the substrings are equal, then you scan to the next non-digit and apply a numeric comparison. If those are equal, switch back to the lexographic comparison. Process the entire string in this fashion. It's fiddly, but shouldn't really be difficult. From a performance view, I highly recommend you don't create/delete the locale every time. Do that once.

Comment: Note on the above: you would need the [_strnicoll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strnicoll-wcsnicoll-mbsnicoll-strnicoll-l-wcsnicoll-l-mbsnicoll-l?view=msvc-170) variants, which can operate on a sub-string.

Comment: _strnicoll is the one, I found. It solves problem.

Comment: Side note: Do no continually create and destroy the locale. Cache it.

Answer (score 0):

Result is here:

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace MajCompare {

struct MajLoc
{
private:
    _locale_t m_loc;
public:
    MajLoc(){ m_loc = _create_locale(LC_COLLATE, "cs-CZ.utf8"); }
    ~MajLoc() { _free_locale(m_loc);}
    _locale_t& GetLocale() { return m_loc; }
};
static MajLoc s_cLoc;

//Vrací -1, 0 1
int CompareNatural(const wchar_t* lhsBegin, const wchar_t* lhsEnd
    , const wchar_t* rhsBegin, const wchar_t* rhsEnd)
{

    wstring wsPom1, wsPom2;
    const wchar_t* itCurLhs = lhsBegin, *itCurRhs = rhsBegin;
    while (!iswdigit(*itCurLhs) && !iswdigit(*itCurRhs) && itCurLhs != lhsEnd && itCurRhs != rhsEnd)
    {
        wsPom1.push_back(*itCurLhs);
        wsPom2.push_back(*itCurRhs);
        if (*itCurLhs != *itCurRhs)
            return _wcsicoll_l(lhsBegin, rhsBegin, s_cLoc.GetLocale());

        itCurLhs++, itCurRhs++;
    }
    if (itCurLhs == lhsEnd || itCurRhs == rhsEnd || iswdigit(*itCurLhs) != iswdigit(*itCurRhs)) //jeden je delší nebo kombinace čísla a písmena, porovnáme původní řetězce bez ohledu na čísla porovnáme standardně
        return _wcsicoll_l(lhsBegin, rhsBegin, s_cLoc.GetLocale());
    else //oba řetězce mají čísla a nejsou na konci
    {
        wstring wsNum1, wsNum2;
        while (iswdigit(*itCurLhs))
            wsNum1.push_back(*itCurLhs++);
        while (iswdigit(*itCurRhs))
            wsNum2.push_back(*itCurRhs++);
        int iNum1 = _wtoi(wsNum1.data());
        int iNum2 = _wtoi(wsNum2.data());
        if (iNum1 != iNum2)
            return iNum1 > iNum2 ? 1 : -1;
        return CompareNatural(itCurLhs, lhsEnd, itCurRhs, rhsEnd);
    }
}

int CompareNatural(const wchar_t* lsFirst, const wchar_t* lsSecond)
{
    const wchar_t* it1 = lsFirst;
    while (*it1 != '\0')it1++;
    const wchar_t* it2 = lsSecond;
    while (*it2 != '\0')it2++;
    return CompareNatural(lsFirst, it1, lsSecond, it2);
}
};
```